# Finding $F'(1)$ when $F(x)=\int_{x^3}^4 \sqrt{4+t^2}\,dt$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

Differentiation under integral sign Jam 2019:

> If $F(x)=\int_{x^3}^{4}\sqrt{4+t^2}\,dt$  for all $ x\in \mathbb R$ then $F'(1)$ equals ?

$F'(x)=  -\sqrt{4+x^6}(3x^2)$

$F'(1)=-3\sqrt{5}$

Is there any mistake ?

Comment: It is fine except that you typed $F(1)$ for $F'(1)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you sir and edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. There is no mistake. In the future, if you have any doubt, you can use Wolfram Alpha to check the value of this.

Comment: I am not familiar with this website I am checking right now thanks.